# Is there a way to restrict number of decimal places shown for a number in output in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

I am trying to display how much more a customer needs to spend in order to get free shipping on this website. I have the code working, but the output is not displayed as I expected. The price for the product is **29.99** but the result of the below handlebars code is returning the value **5.010000000000002**. Is there a way in handlebars (or html) to display only the **5.01** and not the rest?

```
{{subtract 35 price.without_tax.value}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Handlebars, but I can tell you that in plain JavaScript, you would handle this with [Number's toFixed() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
var output = 35 - 29.99;

console.log(output); // 5.010000000000002
console.log(output.toFixed(2)); // 5.01
```

Comment: Why is it that 35-29.99 returns more than just 5.01?

Comment: This is an issue with most all programming languages. It has to do with how floating point numbers are interpreted. For more information, I recommend this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Looks like this is a platform issue for me as I cannot write my own helpers in Handlebars on BigCommerce. Will have to find something from their library of helpers, otherwise this would have worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can register an helper using registerHelper and use it for the conversion.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('distanceFixed', function(distance) {
return distance.toFixed(2);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/T7knB/