# Set decimal places in visulization in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I'd like to set decimal places with I create visulization in Kibana 7.12. The visualization could be TSVB, Gauge, aggregation, or lens. I want to show the average of a field for example. So I can't change the index pattern. I found that might be using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509133/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-number-of-decimal-places-shown-for-a-number-in-output) helps in TSVB aggregation, but the solution doesn't work.

```
{{ avg.v.last.formatted }}
 Handlebars.registerHelper('function', function(v) {
 return v.toFixed(2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Kibana > Stack Management > Advanced Settings > Number Format** to set decimals.
For example, [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFzeK.png) shows the decimals after the point.
When adjustments are made from the **Advanced Settings** section as in [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G63Cm.png), the decimal part after the point disappears [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPaBE.png).

Also, you can adjust Byte, Currency, Number, Percent formats. In addition, you can set how many digits these formats appear, and which punctuation mark you want to use in the thousands place. [additional info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4eGR.png)

```
Number Format: 0,0.[000]
New Number Format: 0,0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm aware of advanced setting, but I'd like to define decimal points for an individual dashboard/panel.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Options tab for the Gage or Metric. Choose "Custom" for the Data Formatter and use a numeral.js format string (eg "0." specifies nothing after the decimal).

[image]